# Quais as diferenças ao incluir valores (vindo de um form por exemplo), em uma query montada no PHP e executada no MYSQL, dentre as formas abaixo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho estudado e visto que existem formas diferentes de se tratar dados antes de inseri-los em uma *query* que é executada no banco de dados.

Tenho algumas dúvidas quanto a segurança e a questão de impedir alguns ataques como SQL injection, etc...

Utilizo algumas formas, muito por recomendação, só que sem entender o porquê.

Gostaria de saber os riscos e a forma mais recomendada entre os 4 exemplos abaixo.

**OBS**: Eu usei `SELECT` nos exemplos, mas poderia ser um `INSERT` também.

#### 1ª Forma:

```
<?php

  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $senha = $POST['senha'];  

  $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE nome = '$nome' AND senha = '$senha'";

?>
```

#### 2ª forma:

```
<?php

  $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  

  $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE nome = '$nome' AND senha = '$senha'";

?>
```

#### 3ª Forma:

Suponhamos que este código esteja dentro de um método de uma classe e os atributos nome e senha sejam `privates`

```
<?php

  $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE nome = :nome and senha = :senha";

 $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindValue(':nome', $this->__get('nome'));
 $stmt->bindValue(':senha', $this->__get('senha'));
 $stmt->execute();

?>
```

#### 4ª Forma:

Suponhamos que este código esteja dentro de um método de uma classe e os atributos nome e senha sejam `privates`

```
<?php

  $nome = $this->__get('nome');
  $senha = $this->__get('senha');

  $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE nome = :nome and senha = :senha";

  $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
  $stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
  $stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: Thiaguinho, esse acréscimo que fez a pergunta não tem relação com todo o resto dela e dado que a pergunta original já foi respondida, sugiro que você abra uma nova pergunta tratando esta outra dúvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1ª Forma:

Completamente insegura, está propenso a sofrer ataque de [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/101). Pega o dados de forma direta como o PHP entrega nativamente o que vem de fora e usa na *query*.

> 2ª Forma:

Dá uma limpadinha no conteúdo das variáveis citadas, de acordo com um critério, mas é muito básico, só limpa alguns absurdos. Pode ser útil e muitas vezes deveria ser complementar a outros tipos de proteção, porque ele limpa coisas diferentes, não é pra limpar SQL, só *strings* mal formadas. Quase todo mundo se preocupa em limpar só um tipo de problema e isto está errado, embora possa causar menos problemas. Esta técnica é útil para limpeza, mas não para combater SQL Injection.

> 3ª Forma:

Aqui não limpa esses absurdos mas usa uma API que está preparada para lidar com o conteúdo externo de forma mais segura, pelo menos não ocorrerá SQL Injection.

Obviamente tem a diferença que não está pegando a entrada de dados de forma direta e sim em objeto que já fez isto de alguma forma. Se ele limpa algo mais e se pega de forma correta não temos como saber. Nem mesmo dá para ter certeza que ele pega algum dado externo. Nem podemos saber se `__get()` deveria ser usado aí, quase sempre que eu vejo isto fico pensando se não deveria ter usado um *array* associativo simples mesmo, quem sabe até o já criado pelo PHP como feito antes.

Se há alguma dúvida se estar em uma classe é melhor ou mais seguro, é quase certo que não, tem potencial para ser pior, depende do que a pessoa fizer.

> 4ª Forma:

O mesmo aqui, a diferença é que usou variáveis antes, de forma geral desnecessárias porque a única vantagem é ser ligeiramente mais rápido, em uma linguagem que não é rápida em uma operação que é lenta, então não faz diferença real.